Como puedo ajustar el tamaño de la imagen utilizando Bootstrap

Codigo: En el comentario  esta el codigo que estoy usando. Agradezco su ayuda! (Si necesitan agregar codigo de CSS lo pueden hacer, Gracias)


<body>

  <!-- Containers -->
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="img/containers/promocion-1.png" class="imagen-rectangular rounded">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="img/containers/promocion-2.png" class="imagen-cuadrada rounded">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img src="img/containers/promocion-3.png" class="imagen-cuadrada rounded">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




Necesito ayuda con este codigo, se puede ver en la imagen que señale las imagenes con las que necesito ayuda. Necesito que las imagenes queden con esas dimensiones y ya he intentado de mil maneras pero aun no encuentro solucion alguna para esto. Es un trabajo para el instituto y realmente no encontre solucion, agradezco su ayuda. Gracias!!

sin CSS no creo que se pueda reproducir tu problema, asegúrate de poner un [mcve]

Hola Juan, "Si necesitan agregar codigo de CSS lo pueden hacer, Gracias", tu frase parece indicar que nos has hecho un css, por lo que no es esperable que obtengas lo que buscas, corrigeme si me equivoco, edita tu pregunta y agrega el css,

"¿Cómo puedo ajustar el tamaño de la imagen utilizando Bootstrap?" ¿De cuál de todas las imágenes estás hablando? Lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta. Procura siempre ser lo más específico posible. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Yo si entendí lo de las imágenes y el código. Lo que no entendí es lo de "ajustar el tamaño" ¿ajustarlo, como?

@MarcePuente Se refiere a que acepta respuestas que tengan nuevo CSS adicional a lo que Bootstrap ya tiene

@Ah, entiendo, aunque parece que el OP, está menos interesado que nosotros en la pregunta, jaja!
